# nslcd: Errors in /var/log/messages Deleted User

Tags: linux, ldap

I'm running a Linux LDAP environment with multiple servers on the domain.  As we have added and removed users from our environment, I started getting these error messages:

```
Nov  9 05:07:25 ops1 nslcd[1377]: [35895e] lookup of user cn=Deleted1 User,ou=People,dc=company,dc=net failed: No such object
Nov  9 05:07:25 ops1 nslcd[1377]: [35895e] ldap_result() failed: No such object
Nov  9 05:07:25 ops1 nslcd[1377]: [35895e] lookup of user cn=Deleted2 User,ou=People,dc=company,dc=net failed: No such object
Nov  9 05:07:25 ops1 nslcd[1377]: [35895e] ldap_result() failed: No such object
```

The users showing up are only users who I have deleted.  Not just recently, either.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to this in this bug:

http://tracker.clearfoundation.com/view.php?id=1752

Basically, I had a group that was still referencing those users as members even though I had deleted them.  In my case, they were part of the uniqueMember list.